# Adding line in Dia automatically sets to centre?

Tags: dia

I'm trying to annotate a picture with the Dia application, by placing description boxes connected to arrows pointing to certain points on picture.  However the arrows keep snapping to the centre of the workspace, how can I avoid this happening?

I've looked through all the preferences panes but couldn't seem to find anything to alter this behaviour.  An idea I had was to place a box beneath the image, then snap the lines to it that way.  Seems like a very odd behaviour when looking at what OmniGraffle, and Visio do.

Please help!

Gareth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, set "Snap to Objects", and this can be set permanently in File-> Preferences -> Diagrams Defaults -> connection Points -> Snap to Object